# String cannot be converted to JSONObject in Android

Tags: android

I'm implementing the JSONParsing but it getting the JSONException of org.json.JSONException: Value true at Status of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.Thanks in advanced.

Here is my Json String

**{"Upd_Post_ActivityResult":{"ResponseItem":"103_20150900021028","Status":"true"}}**

Here is the JSON Parsing

```
 if (result != null) {
                            try
                            {
                                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
                                String jsonResult = jsonObj.toString().trim();
                                Log.e("jsonResult ", " = " + jsonResult);

                                JSONObject json_Upd_Post_ActivityResult = jsonObj.getJSONObject("Upd_Post_ActivityResult");
                                Log.e("getAllActivity_List ", " = " + json_Upd_Post_ActivityResult.toString());

                                JSONObject jobj1 = json_Upd_Post_ActivityResult.getJSONObject("Status");
                                String strStatusObj = jobj1.toString();
                                Log.e("strStatusObj "," = " + strStatusObj);

                                if(strStatusObj.equals("true"))
                                {
                                    Log.e("StartMark Url Uploaded ", "Succesfully !!!!!");
                                    Log.e("Status ", "True");
                                    int imagesArray = imgItemArray.size();
                                    Log.e("imagesArray "," = "+imagesArray);


                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Log.e("Status ","False");
                                }
                            }
                            catch (JSONException je)
                            {
                                je.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
```

Here is log error

```
09-18 06:41:02.543  20427-20490/? W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value true at Status of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
09-18 06:41:02.543  20427-20490/? W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
09-18 06:41:02.543  20427-20490/? W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:613)
09-18 06:41:02.543  20427-20490/? W/System.err﹕ at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.AddPost$7$1.doInBackground(AddPost.java:320)
09-18 06:41:02.543  20427-20490/? W/System.err﹕ at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.AddPost$7$1.doInBackground(AddPost.java:286)
09-18 06:41:02.543  20427-20490/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
09-18 06:41:02.543  20427-20490/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-18 06:41:02.543  20427-20490/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
09-18 06:41:02.543  20427-20490/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-18 06:41:02.543  20427-20490/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-18 06:41:02.543  20427-20490/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: `status` is a string, so use `json_Upd_Post_ActivityResult.getString("Status");`

Comment: Great it's working. But what is the difference JSONObject and getString. It is also JSONObject  ("Status").

Comment: Consider using Google Gson library to simplify json parsing, that's great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below approach:

```
JSONObject jobj1 = json_Upd_Post_ActivityResult.getJSONObject("Status");
String strStatusObj = jobj1.toString();
```

Status is not a JSONObject. So instead to getJSONObject("Status") you have to use 
`String strStatusObj = json_Upd_Post_ActivityResult.getString("Status")`;

Answer (score 1):

i have done few changes in your code , please check...

try
                            {
                                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
                                String jsonResult = jsonObj.toString().trim();
                                Log.e("jsonResult ", " = " + jsonResult);

```
                            JSONObject json_Upd_Post_ActivityResult = jsonObj.getJSONObject("Upd_Post_ActivityResult");
                            Log.e("getAllActivity_List ", " = " + json_Upd_Post_ActivityResult.toString());

                            String strStatusObj = json_Upd_Post_ActivityResult.getString("Status");
                            Log.e("strStatusObj "," = " + strStatusObj);
                            if(strStatusObj.equals("true"))
                            {
                                Log.e("StartMark Url Uploaded ", "Succesfully !!!!!");
                                Log.e("Status ", "True");
                                int imagesArray = imgItemArray.size();
                                Log.e("imagesArray "," = "+imagesArray);


                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Log.e("Status ","False");
                            }
                        }
                        catch (JSONException je)
                        {
                            je.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
JSONObject jobj1 = json_Upd_Post_ActivityResult.getJSONObject("Status");
```

to

```
String strStatusObj = json_Upd_Post_ActivityResult.getString("Status");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below and let me know whether it is working or not

```
String str=json_Upd_Post_ActivityResult.getString("Status");
```